# What does it mean for an Aria label to be localized?

Tags: html, localization, accessibility, wai-aria

I am supposed to add an aria label and a specification was that it be localized. I was wondering what is meant by this? The code I currently have is below:

```
<a href="link"><i class="button" aria-label="back button">
```

How can I change this code so that the label is "localized"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Localized`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_localisation) means it's translated into different languages.

```
<a href="link"><i class="button" aria-label="back button">
```

would become:

```
<a href="link"><i class="button" aria-label="botón de retroceso">
<a href="link"><i class="button" aria-label="zurück knopf">
```

You likely want to make this a proper system and you may have to think about right to left languages and what that means for your design etc...